# how put a html args in a message of grails?

Tags: html, grails, encoding, message

I wish to insert into message a line like "view.mail.warning". It contains a html code, but using encodeAs="html", the message shows a href ... too and does not show a link. What is the correct way for do these things?. I don't want to insert the message in parts :(.

In a gsp:

> <"p style='color:#ddd; font-size:12px; text-align:center;'> <"g:message code="view.mail.warning"  encodeAs="html>

In message.properties:

> <"view.mail.warning= textPart1 <"a href=['http://page.com']> <"g:message code="view.pageName"/>  textPart2 <"a href='mailto:support@page.com'">'support@page.com' textPart3

Comment: Can you paste the exact text which you have defined for "view.mail.warning" in messages.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way /is/ to insert it in parts. However, if you /must/ include html in your properties file you can. What you can not include there however, is GSP/taglibs. Your call to g:message will never be parsed/executed. Messages from the resources are just strings. The following are perfectly valid:

### messages.proprties

```
view.mail.warning=<p>I {0} do html in here!</p><em>But I {1} shouldn't.</em>
```

### GSP

```
<g:message code="view.mail.warning" args="['can', 'really']" />
```

### Output

```
<p>I can do html in here!</p><em>But I really shouldn't.</em>
```

A few things to note about this. As you can see you can pass arguments to your message codes. They are ordinal, and start a zero. This way you can tokenize your message and even pass values from your GSP to your messages.

This is the correct way to use message resource bundles in Grails.

Comment: yes, but if you put => view.mail.warning=<p>I {0} do html in here!</p><em>But I {1} shouldn't.</em> i want that output dont show <p> </p> or some with html code.

Answer (score 0):

**For example:**

**message.properties**

> view.mail.warning= >p>I can do html in here!>/p> >p>But I really shouldn't.>/p>

**GSP**

Output

> I can do html in here!>/p> >p>But I really shouldn't.

i want insert into message properties, message with strings+html